# Tmux1.8 scroll speed

Tags: scroll, tmux

My tmux version is 1.8, and I want to slow down the "scroll speed".
What I've tried:

Add:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi WheelUpPane send -N1 -X scroll-up
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi WheelDownPane send -N1 -X scroll-down

bind -Tcopy-mode WheelUpPane send -N1 -X scroll-up
bind -Tcopy-mode WheelDownPane send -N1 -X scroll-down
```

to ~/.tmux.conf, then run

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

The output error is like:

```
.../.tmux.conf:11: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]
```

My .tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g history-limit 8000 
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

setw -g mouse-resize-pane on
setw -g mouse-select-pane on
setw -g mouse-select-window on
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

It looks like I am on the right way but using the wrong tmux-conf syntax due to the OLD tmux version.
(Is there any way that avoids updating tmux or using extensions? I am not allowed to update or install extensions on this machine)

Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: as the errmsg indicates `bind-key` does not support `-T`. u should use `-t`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replace -T with -t and the errors remain the same.